# Query about Javascript exception handling

Tags: javascript, exception

I am confused about the Javascript exception handling I wanted to clear which error can Javascript catch or which can only be handling with if elses
like in case below in first case I end  up into catch block because of undefined variable but in other case I  stayed in the try block(and would have to use if else for catching that) inspiteof both are "not defined"

first:

```
try {
    var x = 90;
    var value = x / y;
}
catch (err) {
    document.write(err.name + ": " + err.message + "<br/>");
}
```

second :

```
function add(x, y) {
    var resultString = "Hello! The result of your math is: ";
    var result = x + y;
    // return resultString + result; not returning  anything; hence, "undefined" also
}

try {
    var addResult = add(2, 3);
    document.write(" the result is : " + addResult + "<br/>");
} catch (err) {
    document.write(err.name + ": " + err.message + "<br/>");
}
```

Why I am not ending up in to catch block in second case also?

Please clear my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have not defined y anywhere so that throws an exception which is been caught by the catch block, But in the second case you have defined `addResult=undefined` and you are just displaying the value, so there is no exception

If your first case was

```
try {
    var x = 90;
    var y = undefined;
    var value = x / y;
}
catch (err) {
    document.write(err.name + ": " + err.message + "<br/>");
}
```

Then there would have been no exception in first case also.

Hope you got it :)

Comment: so in the second case I am initializing the addResult with "undefined" which is considered as initial value. and in the first I am not even initializing y with "undefined"

Comment: @staticvoidmain even `var y;` makes `y` a valid variable with the `undefined` value that can be used in expressions.

Comment: @staticvoidmain  Jan is right, no need to define it as undefined, just need to define it.

Answer (score 1):

Because there aren't any errors in the second example. The only issue is that `addResult` doesn't return anything, which leads to the `undefined` value. However, this is not an error.
Your first example catches an exception just because the `y` variable wasn't event declared (it doesn't even has the `undefined` value).

You can see this in action here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Error
try{
    alert(x);
}catch(e){
    alert(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
}
//Ok
try{
    var x;
    alert(x);
}catch(e){
    alert(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
}
</script>
```